# What does being a hollow shell mean?

Tags: phrases

What does " hollow shell" mean in the following context.

> So, why did France fall so easily? It is too easy to point to the
>   cause usually cited in textbooks--that Napoleon III's France was a 
>   **hollow shell.** That might have been true, but so was Austria, so was
>   Russia, so was the Ottoman Empire, and they took much longer to fall
>   from grace. It is possible that France fell first because of Prussia's
>   absolute advantage in strength on the Continent; it was in the wrong
>   place at the wrong time in the face of such a strong enemy.

http://www.sparknotes.com/history/european/1871/section5.rhtml

Comment: It is a metaphor that comes from animals with shells, like snails and shellfish. You find empty shells on the beach - they have no life in them. 
A "***hollow shell***" is something that has the external form of something, but lacks the life inside it and it cannot  perform its proper purpose. France was not a state that could work properly  and as a consequence could easily  fall pray to its enemies.

Comment: Think of an empty turtle shell.

Answer (score 1):

All of the structure is there, but there is no life. "He was like a hollow shell after his wife died, performing mechanically through his daily routines."

Answer (score 1):

In that context, the phrase "hollow shell" means that France had the semblance of military power without the substance of it. As a metaphor, it's an apt one. The metaphorical meaning most directly evoked is that of impotent ordnance: for example, an artillery shell without powder or another explosive inside. Reaching beyond that metaphor, the meaning evoked is the sense that a shell without something inside is weak, fragile--just as an empty egg shell collapses easily and completely when stressed, so fell France.